# What means describe a Lie Group explicitly?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

I have given the Lie goup $G=\{g\in GL(2,\mathbb R)|g^TBg=B\}$ with $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Now I have to describe the Lie group $\frak g$ and then the Lie Algebra $G$ explicitly. I'm not sure what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write down G as a Matrices of a certain form.

I.e.

$$G = \begin{bmatrix}
g_{1,1} & g_{1,2} \\
g_{1,2} & g_{2,2} 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

such that the entries have certain properties.

Comment: But is this really more explicit than the description already given? I can see where op‘s confusion is coming from…